# "Explore from Here" for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows 7 is beautiful but, for me, certain things went way way backwards. One of these is the inability to "Explore from Here" as I used to do on Windows XP.

Is there really no way to "Explore from Here" on this super advanced system?

If there is a way to do this, how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar question asked previously.  Check out this question, maybe some of the suggested replacements for File Explorer will have what you are looking for:
[Windows Explore alternative for Windows 7 (file browser like XP)](https://superuser.com/questions/223843/windows-explore-alternative-for-windows-7-file-browser-like-xp)

Comment: Thanks. This is a great resource but unfortunately each solution offered there is either an additional tool (I want something that modifies the built-in Windows Explorer) or XP oriented. +1 anyway for the good intentions.