# Windows Explorer's folder selection moving up and down when selected

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows 7 file browser left pane(Tree View) of Windows explorer really annoys me.

When I expand(double click) a folder which is in the half of the screen it is moved to the bottom of the screen. Some times an item is moved to the top of the screen. Screen here I mean is the scroll pane.

How to disable this option and make work like Windows xp?

Is it good to use third party applications replacing Windows explorer like this link -

- [Windows Explore alternative for Windows 7 (file browser like XP)](https://superuser.com/questions/223843/Windows-explore-alternative-for-Windows-7-file-browser-like-xp)?

Here [is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4Lt7YlNtoY) which demonstrates what I am experiencing which annoys a lot.
My eyes got used to the explorer pane for the past 14 years (Windows 95, 98, xp). Now Windows 7 changes everything and this one among that.

What is the point of moving a folder to the bottom?  They created this option to explore the folders which was good and now if it is moved to the bottom then we again have to scroll it up to see the subfolders (though we can see the subfolders at the right I want it like the other old versions were you can see it in the left without the folders mixed with other files)

Besides, I mostly use the keyboard shortcut to explore folders and this really sucks.

Comment: That's probably the *least* of the problems that Windows 7's Explorer introduced! Even things that worked in Vista (such as the left pane auto-scrolling left/right if a folder name was too long) no longer work in Win7. Going from XP to 7 it's worse, due to a useless Details pane (& who came up with the stupid 15 file limit?), no statusbar to show free space, no Up button, Alt+Enter not working in the left pane... However, no point ranting & raving here (or elsewhere). If you don't like it just stick to XP till it's dead & buried, or install *Classic Shell*, or replace Explorer altogether.

Comment: @Bob yes you are right. double clicking a folder in the tree view either goes to top in the scroll pane or goes botom... mostly for me it goes bottom.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware (as mentioned in the comments I've been annoyed by the exact same issue), Microsoft's official response is "it's a feature, not a bug". Not sure how they can say that with a straight face, but there are many posts (such as [this one with a partial solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-explorer-expands-folders-inappropriately/50a81b05-da98-4d55-821d-55ffbbd0e998) and [this one which recommends installing Classic Shell](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/64517-undesired-windows-explorer-behavior.html)) covering the topic.

The bottom line is there is no perfect fix for this behaviour yet.

**Edit:** After writing this, and to answer your question about whether there are good third-party explorer alternatives, I once again went in search for a suitable alternative for myself.... For your case, if you find the folder movement to be annoying enough and it can't be turned off, then yes, a replacement is probably a good idea for you. The question you link to has several other alternatives (or links to pages listing them, at least). Browse, search, try, and choose at will. (Personally, I think I'm in love. [CubicExplorer](http://www.cubicreality.com/ce/) suits my needs perfectly.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. It still drops down, but all sub-folders show.

In Windows Explorer, click on Organize and then Folder and Search Options. Under Navigation Pane, check the box "Automatically expand to current folder." This apparently is a tricky one, though, because some people online have said to uncheck that box to fix the problem! For me, anyway, now all sub-folders show up.